# Wrong output after calculate PHP

Tags: php, percentage

I'm having a bit of a problem with calculating in PHP. The output echo has a wrong value. For example the echo with 3500, should be 475. Instead I get an 525? Where I am going  wrong?

I'm trying to create a system to calculate a service fee. The fee will be automaticly generated by sum. For the first part of 2500 euros, the service fee will be 15%. For the second part (part between 2500 and 5000) the fee will be 10% etc. I've wrote the following code, but my output (echo) is incorrect. Without the `exit;` it just keeps looping. Whats wrong in my code? Does anyone have a suggestion. I'm a PHP newbee BTW, so any help would be appreciated!

```
<?

### Sum ###
$som = 3500; // example sum 3500 (2500 first part 15% / 1000 second part 10%)

/* Output should be with 3500 : 
15% of 2500 = 375 + 10% of 1000 = 100 (part above 2500) TOTAL of 475. 
My output is 525??? :s */


### 15% first 2500 ###
if ($som < 2500); {
$uitkomst = $som / 100 * 15; 
echo $uitkomst;
exit; }

### 10% between 2500 - 5000 ###
if ($som >2500 && $som < 5000); {   
$iv1 = 2500 / 100 * 15;
$ts = $som - 2500;
$iv2 = $ts / 100 * 10;
$iv1 + $iv2 = $uitkomst; 
echo $uitkomst;
exit; }

### 5% between 5000 - 10.000 ###
if ($som >5000 && $som <10000); {   
$iv1 = 2500 / 100 * 15;
$iv2 = 2500 / 100 * 10;
$ts = $som - 5000;
$iv3 = $ts / 100 * 5;
$iv1 + $iv2 + $iv3 = $uitkomst; 
echo $uitkomst; 
exit; }

### 1% between 10.000 and 200.000 ###
if ($som >10000 && $som <200000); { 
$iv1 = 2500 / 100 * 15;
$iv2 = 2500 / 100 * 10;
$iv3 = 5000 / 100 * 5;
$ts = $som - 10000;
$iv4 = $ts / 100 * 1;
$iv1 + $iv2 + $iv3 + $iv4 = $uitkomst; 
echo $uitkomst;
exit; }

### 0.5% over 200.000 ###
if ($som >200000); {    
$iv1 = 2500 / 100 * 15;
$iv2 = 2500 / 100 * 10;
$iv3 = 5000 / 100 * 5;
$iv4 = 190000 / 100 * 1;
$ts = $som - 200000;
$iv5 = $ts / 100 * 0.5;
$iv1 + $iv2 + $iv3 + $iv4 + $iv5 = $uitkomst; 
echo $uitkomst;
exit; }
?>
```

Comment: You say your script keeps running on forever without the exit?  Can you post your loop construct, please?

Comment: Your $uitkomst assigment is backwards. The left operand gets set to the value of the expression on the right.

Comment: This looks horrible and hard to maintain, you should have an associative array linking amounts to percentages and use a `while` loop, substracting amounts until you reach `0`. Now you are repeating yourself a lot and changing a percentage or amount will require lots of code changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep this in mind the next time I'm programming.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong with your code.

First and foremost, you have a conditional statement that does variable assignment, but the variable is local to the conditional and therefore if the conditional is not true, then the variable is never assigned for later use

```
$uitkomst = 0; //you need to add this.
if ($som < 2500); {
$uitkomst = $som / 100 * 15;
```

The next issue is that your variable assignment is backwards, php is left to right, not right to left, in the following statement you're assigning the value of `$uitkomst` to `$iv2` and to `$iv2`

```
$iv1 + $iv2 = $uitkomst;
```

Which needs to be:

```
$uitkomst = $iv1 + $iv2;
```

And that adjustment needs to be made in several places of your code.

And lastly, you have `;`'s that trail after your conditional statements. While I'm not even sure how this functions at all, these need to be removed:

```
if ($som >10000 && $som <200000); {
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
if ($som >10000 && $som <200000){
```

And that adjustment needs to be made in several places of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are empty:

```
if ($som >2500 && $som < 5000);
```

lose the ';'

also, make a habit of enclosing tests in brackets e.g.

```
if(($som >10000) && ($som <200000))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind next time. I'm just beginning with PHP, so I appriciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better approach for you.  Add as many rules as you would like.

```
<?php

### Sum ###
$som = 3500; // example sum 3500 (2500 first part 15% / 1000 second part 10%)

$rules = array(
    // lower bound => array( 
    //    'percent' => percent to charge for this rule, 
    //    'upper' => upper bound for this rule 
    // )
    0 => array( 'percent' => 0.15, 'upper' => 2500 ),
    2500 => array( 'percent' => 0.10, 'upper' => 5000 ),
    5000 => array( 'percent' => 0.05, 'upper' => 10000 ),
    10000 => array( 'percent' => 0.01, 'upper' => 200000 ),
    200000 => array( 'percent' => 0.005, 'upper' => null ), 
);

$fee = 0;
$toCalculate = $som;
foreach( $rules as $lower => $rule ) {
    // If there's nothing left to calculate, break
    if($toCalculate <= 0) break;

    $rule['upper'] = $rule['upper'] ? $rule['upper'] : $toCalculate;

    // Amount to apply the current fee percent to
    $current = min($rule['upper'], $toCalculate);

    // Add fee generated by current rule
    $fee += $rule['percent'] * $current;
    $toCalculate -= $current;
}

echo 'Fee: ' . $fee;
```

Comment: Nice job.  Beat me to it.  I wrote a decimal -> roman numeral converter that works very similar.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This works great and keeps the code clean. I will study your code, to improve my PHP skills

Answer (score 0):

```
$iv1 + $iv2 = $uitkomst;
```

The problem is here, it is: $uitkomst = $iv1 + $iv2;  because, in php and in other language, the assign is: $var = val; and not vice-versa ... and i suggest you to use elseif and do the echo, after the elseif and after do the exit...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This will help me improving my PHP skills.